# C# Audio Visualizer

Tags: c#, аудио, визуализация

Собственно, нужно написать прогу на c#, которая берëт текущий звук системы(ну или конкретного девайса) и преобразует его в массив чисел. Соответственно, чем выше число - тем больше "вес" частоты. Я копался на форумах, на гитхабе нашëл пару проектов, в которых разобраться не смог, ибо умом не блистаю. Нашëл несколько библиотек, но почти умер, пытаясь в них разобраться. Одна вообще не ассемблере была... Помогите, пожалуйста))

Comment: Библиотека NAudio, преобразование Фурье, примеров полинтернета.

Comment: @aepot прошу прощения, я написал, что облазил форумы и не нашëл подобного(

Comment: Я знаю, я тупой) Можете сказать конкретный метод или дать ссылку на подобную тему?